# file system "/boot" is not a FAT EFI system partition (ESP) file system

Tags: arch-linux, parted

I'm trying to install Arch Linux in a VM from scratch.
Following the wiki, I see there are no answers to my question.
I'm trying `bootctl install`
and it returns `file system "/boot" is not a FAT EFI system partition (ESP) file system.`
Running `parted` in `tty2` and typing `print` gives me

[image]

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Stupid question: did you format the ESP correctly (`mkfs.fat -F32 /dev/sda1`)?

Comment: Also check your `/etc/fstab`: ESP should be mounted as `vfat` and also check that the ESP is actually mounted as `/boot`.

Answer (score 2):

I had the same errors when trying to `bootctl install` on a nvme SSD device.

I found [this forum post](https://bbs.archlinux.org/viewtopic.php?pid=1626751#p1626751) which says that `parted` is the problem.

I had to follow it exactly and use the exact same programs to solve the problem. The steps are (replace `/dev/sdX` with your device's path):

1. wipe disk to obtain clean state (**WARNING**: this will delete all data on the device!):

> - `# gdisk /dev/sdX`
>
>   - `x` for expert mode
>   - `z` to wipe, accept wipe MBR with `Y`

2. Create new partition table

> - `# cgdisk /dev/sdX`
>
>   - create new partition
>   - with default start (just hit enter)
>   - size of `512MiB`
>   - partition type `EF00` (ESP)
>   - give the partition a name (e.g. `boot`)
>   - write
>   - quit

3. Format boot partition

> ```
> # mkfs.fat -F32 /dev/sdX1
> ```